# Is it mandatory for tables to be in relationship to apply Join on Them?

Tags: sql-server

Is it mandatory for tables to be in relationship to apply Join on Them?if yes then Elaborate with example If No then Elaborate with Example.. Thank you

Comment: In logical sense yes, because then the result doesn't make any sense if you just join two things that don't have anything to do with each other, but there's no requirement for having foreign keys or anything like that for joining.

Comment: Isn't easier to try than to post a question? Well...for _this_ question probably not...

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not mandatory for two tables to be in relationships to apply join on them.

When you think of word "Join" in your mind, you actually bring two thing closer on some common ground, layer, interface etc. So, as long as your two tables have any row value common, you can this common values/values to join those two tables. So, lets say you have table A, B. A have three(or anything) column a1,a2,a3. Similarly, B have 5(or anything) number of columns. IF any of the columns in A have same value as any column in B in any row, you can use this common value to join. 
Example:
select column name from A left join (or outer or inner) B on A.column = B.column

Relationship is a more specific case of intentionally bringing values common to two tables. Example: Foreign Key, Primary Key. You are forcing your table containing foreign key to have same values as table having primary key.

Comment: Makes sense, but in practice, (in most cases) I do not see a reason why you would not create a relationship between two columns from two separate tables that are supposed to be referring to each other.

Otherwise, if they have the same value but are not related in any sense, I do not see a valid reason (in most cases) why you would create a join between them.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all for `sql-Server`. Tables don't need a keyed relationship for them to be joined to one another.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT * FROM
Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Id = Table2.Id
```

Table1's Id column doesn't need to be keyed to Table2's id column for this to executed.

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL Server? No, tables do not need to have any formal relation to be used in any type of a join.

Since you're asking for an example, consider the Numbers or Tally table. It's basically a table with one column that has an increasing number as it's value. (i.e. first row is 1, second row is 2, etc.) This is useful for lots of calculations, including generating date ranges, such as all the days someone was traveling:

```
-- Assume a table "Numbers exists with one column, "num":
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Numbers](
    [Num] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Numbers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Num] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

We can then use this by joining it with a completely unrelated table that has date ranges. We want to list all the dates within any date range:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#source') is not null drop table #source
go

create table #source(
    id int,
    startdate date,
    enddate date
)
go

insert into #source values (1, '2013-12-28', '2014-01-12')
insert into #source values (1, '2014-01-10', '2014-01-22')
insert into #source values (2, '2014-12-22', null)
insert into #source values (2, '2014-12-01', '2015-01-10')
go
--  */

declare @earlydate date, @latedate date

-- Start and end dates of the range we're trying to evaluate within
set @earlydate = '2014-01-01'
set @latedate = '2014-12-31'

;with fixed as (
    select
        id,
        (select max (start_date) from (values (#source.startdate), (@earlydate)) as sd(start_date)) as startdate, -- calculate the LATER of the start dates
        (select min (end_date) from (values (coalesce(enddate, cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date))), (@latedate)) as ed(end_date)) as enddate -- calculate the EARLIER of the end dates
    from #source
)
select
    id,
    DateAdd(dd, num-1, startdate)
from fixed
cross apply Numbers
where DateAdd(dd, num, startdate) between startdate and dateadd(dd, 1, enddate)
order by 1,2
```